# How to pass not a function that returns a boolean in another function?

Tags: haskell

I want to negate a function in the if clause of another function like bellow:

```
isBig :: Integer -> Bool
isBig n = n > 9999

function :: Integer -> Integer
function n =
   if not isBig n then ... else ...
```

It complies when it's just 'if isBig n then else' but I'm not sure why it doesn't work for 'not isBig' as I get this error:

*Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type` Integer -> Bool'

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `not (isBig n)`. `not isBig n` tries to pass two arguments to `not`, both `isBig` and `n`. `isBig` is an `Integer -> Bool` but a `Bool` is expected, hence the error.

In general, function application in Haskell is *left-associative*, meaning that an expression like this:

```
f 2 3 5
```

Is parsed like this:

```
(((f 2) 3) 5)
```

Likewise, the arrows in function types are *right-associative*, so for example if we had this definition for `f`:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f x y z = x * y + z
```

That type signature is the same as:

```
f :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))
```

So it looks like this as you apply more arguments:

```
   f         :: Int -> (Int -> (Int -> Int))
  (f 2)      ::        (Int -> (Int -> Int))
 ((f 2) 3)   ::                (Int -> Int)
(((f 2) 3) 5 ::                        Int

==

f       :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f 2     ::        Int -> Int -> Int
f 2 3   ::               Int -> Int
f 2 3 5 ::                      Int
```

When you’re applying a chain of functions to an argument, you end up with parentheses associating to the right:

```
f (g (h x))
```

In this case it’s common to use the `$` operator, which is right-associative and has low precedence, just to reduce the nesting of brackets:

```
f $ g $ h x
```

And you can do so in your case: `not $ isBig n`

You can also use composition to factor out the chain of functions and apply it to different arguments elsewhere:

```
fgh = f . g . h

fgh x
==
(f . g . h) x
==
f (g (h x))
```

```
isNotBig = not . isBig

isNotBig n
==
(not . isBig) n
==
not (isBig n)
```